# Streaming a song from a song downloading url

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have a link that directly starts downloading of the song, but I want to stream that song in my app without downloading. Is it possible? Please help me through.

Link is: [http://workintelligentonline.com/church/audio/1New Stories (Highway Blues).wma](http://workintelligentonline.com/church/audio/1New%20Stories%20%28Highway%20Blues%29.wma)

Comment: Please answer somebody.

Comment: I have tried to answer your query based on my understanding of your question. In case you were looking at any further or different details, please enhance your question with specific points.

Answer (score 0):

For your application to play the song, the `decoder` has to read the data from memory. So the streaming data has to stored into a `buffer` or a `page-cache` implementation which is then fed to the decoder.

Once the song playback is completed, the `MediaPlayer` engine is closed which will release the allocated memory too. As long as your application **doesn't** write the contents of the memory into a file, you have technically played a streaming song without downloading.